# Tendermint vs Grandpa & Babe

Tags: protocol, consensus, updates, hardfork

It seems Tezos is moving towards the Tendermint consensus, used by Cosmos. However, wouldn't a Grandpa & Babe consensus mechanism, as used in Polkadot, allow for better block scaling?

EDIT: I am posting a paragraph by Kerman Kohli's article [here](https://tokeneconomy.co/the-state-of-crypto-interoperability-explained-in-pictures-654cfe4cc167), which explains the above:

> *"Polkadot’s consensus mechanism consists of two components: GRANDPA and BABE. GRANDPA is a finality gadget which draws on some ideas behind the GHOST fork choice rule (like Ethereum’s Casper) and BABE is a block production mechanism similar to Cardano’s Ouroboros. The introduction of a finality gadget allows for portions of the chain to be “finalized” and provably never be reverted. Separating the finality gadget from the block production allows for the slower finality gadget to work in a different process from the generation of new blocks in the chain. This means that the actual production of blocks can scale unlike in the PBFT-bound Cosmos Tendermint algorithm."*

Comment: Welcome to TSE! Please try to reformulate your question as a technical specific question otherwise it would be either too broad to answer or just chat which is not what TSE aims to be. Could please precise what kind of scaling you mean ? What aspects you think cosmos and polkadot differ etc. This will give much more info to people on the kind of answer you want and avoid this question become a simple chat.

Comment: This is a great question in general but maybe not a great question for stackexchange. How about a https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos issue?